# React app works locally but the first page "fails to fetch" when deployed

Tags: reactjs

It's my first React App I'm trying to deploy so I'm not really sure which part of the code you guys want to see but here is the link to the Netlify page which shows **"Failed to fetch"** on the landing page: *https://sparkling-blancmange-4f1bd1.netlify.app/*

The console log shows

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
> localhost:8000/blogs:1

It works perfectly when I launch it from VScode with VScode being open.

Things I've tried:

- GitHub Pages by following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hM5viLMJpA&t=172s
  It gave me a 404 error.
- Tried changing the localhost:8000/blogs URL to the same URL as the Netlify link but then I got the error:

> Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON

Here is my first GitHub push:
https://github.com/danyealmateen/dojo-blog
and here is my second attempt
https://github.com/danyealmateen/blog

Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: you are calling http://localhost:8000/blogs in the first page.. for that to work you need to run server in your localhost at 8000 ..   i think your api endPoint for blogs is incorrect.. please check that..

Comment: I have const { data: blog, error, isPending } = useFetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs/' + id)

and     const { data: blogs, isPending, error } = useFetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs'); on the landing page. Is it giving me the error cause im not using  +id on the landing page url?

Comment: then create a  api endPoint in  'http://localhost:8000/blogs' for receiving all posts in your server..

Comment: sorry but this is so new to me that I dont understand what you're saying. What do you mean by creating an api endpoint and how do I do that?

Comment: Could you share your backend code which is running the server in localhost:8000 ?

Comment: as far as I know I dont have any backend code - im hosting this locally

Comment: I don't know .. then how you are getting response for http://localhost:8000/blogs/id .. this endpoint

Comment: As far i understand.. you are following some tutorials.. from that you have created this react app .. which works fine..   now you need to create the express server for this endpoints .. please check the resources or share any links

Comment: Talked to a mate that explained that I've created the app only from the front-end side. Wich means I've done this locally while using a json-server as a fake backend wich means I can't access it from a different device. In short i'll have to make a backend server that the json is simulating. Appreciate your help @sms